# sql for selecting ratio over 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
datekey (number) | value (numeric) | other | values
20230101           10003
20230101           -3
20230101           282345
20230101           -3
20230101           285
20230102           10001
20230102           -3
20230102           22345
20230103           3
20230103           -3
20230103           282345
```

I have above table. I need to do a query (in oracle sql) grouping on the datekey, and selecting the ratio per grouped datekey where values are below a certain threshold vs the total amount per grouped date
I came up with query below:

```
WITH tc AS (SELECT DATEKEY/100 AS MONTH, count(*) total
             FROM mytable where DATEKEY/100 >= 202111 GROUP BY DATEKEY/100)
, lc AS (SELECT DATEKEY/100 AS MONTH, count(*) missing 
FROM mytable fsr where DATEKEY/100 >= 202111 AND value < 1000 GROUP BY DATEKEY/100)
SELECT tc.MONTH, tc.total, lc.missing, lc.missing/tc.total AS perc FROM tc, lc WHERE tc.MONTH = lc.MONTH ORDER BY tc.MONTH desc;
```

resulting in:

```
month.    | total | missing | perc
20230101     5         3        0.60
20230102     3         1        0.3333
20230103     3         2        0.666
```

but I think there are cleaner ways (without with), also utilizing Oracle's ratio_to_report, but I havent been able to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use conditional aggregation for missing values and an *ordinary* counting for the rest.

```
SQL> select datekey,
  2    count(*) as total,
  3    sum(case when value < 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as missing,
  4    round(sum(case when value < 1000 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*), 2) as perc
  5  from test
  6  group by datekey;

   DATEKEY      TOTAL    MISSING       PERC
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  20230101          5          3         .6
  20230102          3          1        .33
  20230103          3          2        .67

SQL>
```